# Solve the d.e $(x+\sqrt{y^2-xy})dy-ydx=0$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

So this is a homogeneous differential equation. 
I use the substitution $y=ux$, $dy=udx+xdu$
And after simplification, got this integral: 
$$
\int\frac{1+\sqrt{u^2-u}}{u\sqrt{u^2-u}}du
$$
I broke it up into two fractions, cancelling out the $\sqrt{u^2-u}$ in one to get, after integration, $\log|u|$ and the other one I have is $$\int \frac{1}{u\sqrt{u^2-u}}du$$

After completing the square I got 
$$
\int\frac{1}{u\sqrt{(u-\frac{1}{2})^2-\frac{1}{4}}}du
$$
This looks like an arcsec trick but I'm not quite sure how to manipulate it to get it into the correct format.

Any tips? Is this the right approach?

Comment: This probably isn't the  arcsec

Comment: Spoiler alert. The result will be

$$\ln(u) + \frac{2\sqrt{1-2u}\sqrt{u-1}}{\sqrt{-u}\sqrt{2u-1}}$$

Comment: @1over137 so the answer must be a complex number? for the denominator to be defined we must have $u<0$ and $u>\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: @Nikunj What comes out from an indefinite integral is nothing but a function. It becomes a complex number, or an imaginary one, only when you substitute some value for $u$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\frac{1 + \sqrt{u^2-u}}{u\cdot\sqrt{u^2 - u}} = \frac{1}{u\cdot \sqrt{u^2-u}} + \frac{1}{u}$$

Once you split into this, you'll have two integrals. The second one is trivial, it will be a log.

The first one can be evaluated by completing the square inside the root as:

$$u \sqrt{\left(u - \frac{1}{2}\right)^2 - \frac{u}{4}}$$

and then make a suitable substitution.

Can you proceed?

**Hint 2**

At this point, use a suitable substitution like

$$y = u - \frac{1}{2}$$

$$\int\frac{1}{\left(y + \frac{1}{2}\right)\sqrt{y^2 - \frac{1}{4}}}\ \text{d}y$$

Now a cute substitution to take may be

$$y = \frac{\sec(z)}{2} ~~~~~~~~~~~ \text{d}y = \frac{1}{2}\tan(z)\sec(z)\ \text{d}z$$

Can you proceed?

**Hint 3**

After the substitution, and after having arranged the integral, you'll get

$$\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{2\sec(z)}{\frac{\sec(z)}{2} + \frac{1}{2}}\ \text{d}z$$

simplify the $2$ and then another non standard substitution will help:

$$k = \tan\left(\frac{z}{2}\right) ~~~~~~~~~~~ \text{d}k = \frac{1}{2}\sec^2\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)\ \text{d}z$$

Can you proceed?

Comment: how would you know to use that substitution $y=\frac{\sec(z)}{2}$ its not standard as far as i know...

Comment: @shoestringfries In a word: experience. But don't worry, I understand that those substitutions (and I mean the tangent and secant ones) are almost never explained in school, and it's a real pity because they "save many lives". Despite what is your math program, I invite you to study those substitutions, namely tangent and secant ones, because they are really helpful with some integrals. Of course there may be other ways to solve it (more tedious and longer).

Comment: my professor said that perhaps using $x=uy$ in the beginning substitution into the original d.e. I may obtain a friendlier integral...but i will try and see both ways

Comment: Namely, $u = \frac{x}{y}$. I tried but things don't get better.. You have to play on the fact that you have a square root with a certain type of argument, so it's preferable to use certain substitutions like the ones illustrated here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution and here overall https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution

Answer (score 2):

Put $u=\frac{1}{t}$ in the integral ($\int \frac{du}{u\sqrt{u^2-u}}$)
To get (after simplification)
$$ \int \frac{-dt}{\sqrt{1-t}}$$
Which evaluates to $$2\sqrt{1-t}+C$$
$$=\color{red}{2\sqrt {\frac{u-1}{u}}+C}$$

Answer (score 2):

Take out $u$ again, and then take $1-\frac{1}{u} = t$, then $\frac{du}{u^2} = dt$.

There you go.

Comment: Please, learn LaTeX.

Answer (score 0):

Try $x=uy$, transform into a separable variable question.

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{|y|}dy-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u}}du=0
\end{equation}

take integral
\begin{equation}
\int \frac{1}{|y|}dy-\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u}}du=c
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\vert (\log |y|)\vert+2\sqrt{1-u}=c
\end{equation}

If $y>0$, $|\log y|=c-2\sqrt{1-u}$, $\because 1-u< 0, \therefore y> x$.

Further, if $0<y<1$, then $\log y<0$, $-\log y=c-2\sqrt{1-u}\Rightarrow y=Ce^{2\sqrt{1-u}}$.

If $y>1$, then $\log y>0$, $\log y=c-2\sqrt{1-u}\Rightarrow y=Ce^{-2\sqrt{1-u}}$.

Similarly, if $y<0$, $|\log (-y)|=c-2\sqrt{1-u}$, $y<x$.

Further, if $-1<y<0$, then $\log (-y)<0$, $-\log (-y)=c-2\sqrt{1-u}\Rightarrow y=-Ce^{2\sqrt{1-u}}$.

If $y<-1$, then $\log (-y)>0$, $\log (-y)=c-2\sqrt{1-u}\Rightarrow y=-Ce^{-2\sqrt{1-u}}$.

Remind that $-C$ is still a constant and can collapse to $C$. Substitute $u=\frac xy$. So

\begin{equation}
y=\begin{cases}
Ce^{-2\sqrt{1-x/y}} & y>1, y>x\\
Ce^{2\sqrt{1-x/y}} & 0<y<1, y>x\\
Ce^{2\sqrt{1-x/y}} & -1<y<0, y<x\\
Ce^{-2\sqrt{1-x/y}} & y<-1, y<x
\end{cases}
\end{equation}